# Добавление дополнительных полей в Сертификат

Tags: ssl, openssl, сертификат

С помощью OpenSSL был получен отдельно сертификат с расширением (.cer) и закрытый ключ. Необходимо чтобы в сертификате содержались поля ИНН и ОГРН организации. Как их в него добавить?

Comment: Любые поля в сертификат добавляются во время его создания, добавлять поля в готовый сертификат нельзя. Как делают сертификат содержащие ИНН и ОГРН не знаю, но подозреваю что вам он нужен для госуслуг или еще для чего то такого. А если так то получить сертификат можно только в специализированных конторах

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Все верно, для госуслуг. Я для тестирования аутентификации через госуслуги пытаюсь использовать свой самоизданный сертификат, но проверки не проходят на сервере и валидность не подтверждается. Получается запрашивать нужно только в удостоверяющем центре?

Comment: Да, именно так. Сайт госуслуг и другие подобные сервисы проверяют валидность как раз на основании того, что сертификат подписан аккредитованным УЦ

Comment: Возможно я неправ, но для ЕСИА (в отличие от СМЭВ) я генерировал свой сертификат, а затем отсылал его на регистрацию вместе с документами (что за организация и куда делать callback). После подтверждения, что ключ зарегистрирован, можно было проверять, используя их тестовый стенд и их тестовые СНИЛС/пароли.

Comment: @rogueCapella да все верно, мне этот сертификат не сразу выдали, поэтому произошла путаница) Сейчас он загружен в аккаунт организации и тесты проходят успешно. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

мне ответила Служба поддержки Единой системы идентификации

1.2.643.100.1 = ОГРН

1.2.643.3.131.1.1 = ИНН организации (с двумя лидирующими нулями)
в итоге при генерации эти поля засовываем в раздел

[req_distinguished_name]

осталось только решить вопрос, как вставить русские буквы в сертификат